# Given the percentage of each range of years, how to calculate the total average of years?

Tags: statistics, average, percentages, percentile

For example, in a pet shop, 35% of cats is 1 ~ 2 years old, 40% is 2 ~ 4 years old and the remaining 25% is 4 ~ 6 years old. How can I know the average of cat's age in this pet shop?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnQdD.png

Comment: Here's a hint: Let there be $100$ cats in total, and then you calculate the average by summing the median value * number of cats in each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question asks for the average age as a range (the same way the group ages are given), consider the case where cats in each group are at the minimum age, then the overall average is:

$$
35\% \cdot 1 + 40\% \cdot 2 + 25\% \cdot 4 = 2.15
$$

Then, work out the same calculation for the maximum ages:

$$
35\% \cdot 2 + 40\% \cdot 4 + 25\% \cdot 6 = 3.8
$$

Therefore the average cat age is between $\,2.15 \,\cdots\, 3.8\,$ years old.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. `Simulating with uniforms` Now *that*'s a nice idea, though likely outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Completely outside. Underlines the fact you should _never_ make a bar chart without specifying the $n.$

Comment: Nice idea(+1). Using midpoints, it's 2.98. A more serious revision of my simulation expt (earlier comment deleted): Simulating a million shops with 20 cats each, using uniforms over bins with 7, 8, and 5 cats per bin, respectively, the average sample mean is 2.975, the min mean 2.415 and the max mean 3.495.

Comment: @BruceET Interesting simulation results. It's no surprise that the sample mean is (essentially) the easily computed $2.98$. I wonder if there's an easy way to get good estimates on the variance - a more interesting statistic than the max and min. And can you estimate the skew?

Comment: @EthanBolker:  I get $S \approx 1.46$ and between 1.00 and 1.87. Could also simulate skewness in the same way, but reluctant to discuss skewness for data sorted into only three bins. Also doubt reliability of cat age data. Do these kitties have birth certificates?

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is an approximation. Assume all the cats between $1$ and $2$ years old are $1.5$ years old. Do the same for the other two groups. Then take the average, weighted by the percentages (or assume there are exactly $100$ cats, as @TobyMark suggests).